# Use grid search to create a matrix with dimension n * 3 in Python

Tags: python, matrix, grid-search

I want to have a matrix like this below, 3 columns, n rows. Each row sums to one.

```
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0.1, 0.9], [0.1, 0.1, 0.8], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7] ...]
```

Is there a library for doing this?

Comment: You need to be more precise, do you want to have all possible combinations, so including `[0.7, 0.2, 0.1]` or is the third dimensions always decreasing and first and second increasing? How about if thrid dimension reaches zero etc?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying my quesiton. I think it'd better have some pattern, like you said that the third dimension should always decreasing and it can reach to 0. All possible combinations could be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to pick 2 partitions out of the 11 slots between 0.0 and 1.0:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
[[n / 10 for n in (a, b - a, 10 - b)] for a, b in combinations_with_replacement(range(11), 2)]
```

This returns:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.1, 0.9],
 [0.0, 0.2, 0.8],
 [0.0, 0.3, 0.7],
 [0.0, 0.4, 0.6],
 [0.0, 0.5, 0.5],
 [0.0, 0.6, 0.4],
 [0.0, 0.7, 0.3],
 [0.0, 0.8, 0.2],
 [0.0, 0.9, 0.1],
 [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 [0.1, 0.0, 0.9],
 [0.1, 0.1, 0.8],
 [0.1, 0.2, 0.7],
 [0.1, 0.3, 0.6],
 [0.1, 0.4, 0.5],
 [0.1, 0.5, 0.4],
 [0.1, 0.6, 0.3],
 [0.1, 0.7, 0.2],
 [0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
 [0.1, 0.9, 0.0],
 [0.2, 0.0, 0.8],
 [0.2, 0.1, 0.7],
 [0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
 [0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
 [0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
 [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
 [0.2, 0.6, 0.2],
 [0.2, 0.7, 0.1],
 [0.2, 0.8, 0.0],
 [0.3, 0.0, 0.7],
 [0.3, 0.1, 0.6],
 [0.3, 0.2, 0.5],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.4],
 [0.3, 0.4, 0.3],
 [0.3, 0.5, 0.2],
 [0.3, 0.6, 0.1],
 [0.3, 0.7, 0.0],
 [0.4, 0.0, 0.6],
 [0.4, 0.1, 0.5],
 [0.4, 0.2, 0.4],
 [0.4, 0.3, 0.3],
 [0.4, 0.4, 0.2],
 [0.4, 0.5, 0.1],
 [0.4, 0.6, 0.0],
 [0.5, 0.0, 0.5],
 [0.5, 0.1, 0.4],
 [0.5, 0.2, 0.3],
 [0.5, 0.3, 0.2],
 [0.5, 0.4, 0.1],
 [0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
 [0.6, 0.0, 0.4],
 [0.6, 0.1, 0.3],
 [0.6, 0.2, 0.2],
 [0.6, 0.3, 0.1],
 [0.6, 0.4, 0.0],
 [0.7, 0.0, 0.3],
 [0.7, 0.1, 0.2],
 [0.7, 0.2, 0.1],
 [0.7, 0.3, 0.0],
 [0.8, 0.0, 0.2],
 [0.8, 0.1, 0.1],
 [0.8, 0.2, 0.0],
 [0.9, 0.0, 0.1],
 [0.9, 0.1, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```